# How to add default standard value to typography element in OptionTree

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [OptionTree 2.3.4](https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) WordPress Plugin. I want to know that how I can add a default/standard ( std ) value to Typography and Background option type? These both option types accepts std values in an array. Is there any way to add default values to these option types? or is there any filter for this task?

Please suggest me some solution. Thanks in advance.